# Get round 2100 parameter limit in SQLServer with hibernate

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, hql

So, I'm trying to run a HQL query on hibernate and SQL server

The query takes a list of files and a list of manifestations. Manifestations are associated with files. The aim of the query is to find all files from a list of files which are linked to manifestations that are *not* on a list of manifestations. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT file.fileref from com.project.FileImpl f, com.project.ManifestationFileImpl mf 
WHERE f.fileref IN filerefs 
AND mf.manifestionRef NOT IN manifestationRefs 
AND f.fileRef= mf.fileRef
```

Where fileRefs and manifestationRefs are both arrays of strings. Unfortunately, when large arrays are passed into this query, it fails because SQL server cannot accept more than 2100 parameters.

Much as I'd like to, this is legacy code which I cannot recode to eliminate the possibility that very large arrays will be passed in.

Is there a way (other than just breaking it down into many smaller queries and iterating though the results) to rewrite this query so that the parameter limit does not occur?

Comment: You could try adding Table Valued Function suggested in this link  https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=981227